# Is it possible to give Enums instance variables of their own type in Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, enums

I'm making a Text Adventure game in Groovy as a sort of exercise, and I'm running into a strange error.

Right now, I have an `enum` for the directions that a player will be able to go, currently containing North, South, East, West, Up, and Down.

I have a `Room` class that holds a `Map` of other connected rooms and their directions. When I add a `Room` to another `Room` at a certain `Direction`, I want to be able to also add the current `Room` to the other `Room` at the *opposite* direction.

Ex: If I add a connection from Room 1 to Room 2 going north, I want to be able to add a connection from Room 2 to Room 1 going south at the same time.

Currently, I am trying to implement this using an `enum` named `Direction` with an attached instance variable `opposite` (of type `Direction`). Is this not allowed? I'm not getting compiler errors or anything, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's the full `enum` declaration:

```
public enum Direction {
    North(South), South(North), East(West), West(East), Up(Down), Down(Up)
    private Direction opposite
    Direction(Direction d){
        opposite = d
    }
    public opposite(){
        return opposite
    }
}
```

And this is the method that I am calling it from:

```
public void addConnection(Direction d, Spot spot){
    connections[d] = spot
    spot.connections[d.opposite()] = this
}
```

where `connections` is a `public Map<Direction, Spot>`.

In this case, an entry gets added to `connections` that looks like this:

```
null:Spot@some_hexadecimal_representation
```

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Groovy seems to circumvent what in Java is [a compilation error](http://ideone.com/lrIZI):

```
Main.java:2: illegal forward reference
    North(South), South(North), East(West), West(East), Up(Down), Down(Up);
          ^
Main.java:2: illegal forward reference
    North(South), South(North), East(West), West(East), Up(Down), Down(Up);
                                     ^
Main.java:2: illegal forward reference
    North(South), South(North), East(West), West(East), Up(Down), Down(Up);
                                                           ^
3 errors
```

The groovy compiler does not complain about that, but initializes the enum values that need forward declarations as `null`:

```
public enum Direction {
    North(South), South(North), East(West), West(East), Up(Down), Down(Up)
    Direction(Direction d){
        println "opposite of $this is $d"
    }
}

Direction.South // Force enum instantiation in GroovyConsole.
```

[Outputs](http://ideone.com/XAg0x):

```
opposite of North is null
opposite of South is North
opposite of East is null
opposite of West is East
opposite of Up is null
opposite of Down is Up
```

One solution that seems to work just fine in Java is [adding a `static` block on the `Direction` class](http://ideone.com/gpTXp) to initialize the `opposite` values. Translated to Groovy, that would be:

```
enum Direction {
    North, South, East, West, Up, Down
    private Direction opposite
    Direction getOpposite() { opposite }

    static {
        def opposites = { d1, d2 -> d1.opposite = d2; d2.opposite = d1 }
        opposites(North, South)
        opposites(East, West)
        opposites(Up, Down)
    }
}

Direction.values().each { 
    println "opposite of $it is $it.opposite"
}
```

Which now [prints the correct values](http://ideone.com/9HgCb):

```
opposite of North is South
opposite of South is North
opposite of East is West
opposite of West is East
opposite of Up is Down
opposite of Down is Up
```

### Update

[Another](http://ideone.com/OPv1v), maybe more straightforward, solution can using the direction indexes on the enum to find the opposites:

```
public enum Direction {
    North(1), South(0), East(3), West(2), Up(5), Down(4)
    private oppositeIndex
    Direction getOpposite() { 
        values()[oppositeIndex]
    }
    Direction(oppositeIndex) { 
        this.oppositeIndex = oppositeIndex
    }
}
```

But i find the first one clearer as it doesn't need those magic numbers for the indexes hehe.

### Update 2

Now, i'm probably getting a bit into golfing lands here, but you can get the opposite direction [without the need of an extra field](http://ideone.com/8J8lv), just using the enum values' `ordinal()` (their index):

```
enum Direction {
    North, South, East, West, Up, Down
    Direction getOpposite() { 
        values()[ordinal() + ordinal() % 2 * -2 + 1]
    }
}
```

It's not as scary as it looks! Even directions (North, East, Up) return the direction at `ordinal() + 1` as their opposite, while odd directions (the other ones) return the ones at `ordinal() - 1`. Of course it is heavily relying on the order of the elements in the enum, but, don't you love the succinctness? =D

Comment: Great solution! This compiles and runs smoothly on my machine, and is very readable. Thank you.

Comment: @BenjaminKovach If you don't want so much readability (or you want to leave a little riddle for future maintainers of the code), take a look at my second update on the answer xD

Comment: +1 Nice solution!  You can also replace the `getOpposite` method with `@Lazy opposite = { values()[ordinal() + ordinal() % 2 * -2 + 1] }()` if you only want to calculate the opposites once (though in this case, it's overkill) ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates as it turns out, you don't even need the closure! `@Lazy opposite = values()[ordinal() + ordinal() % 2 * -2 + 1]` works just fine!

Answer (score 2):

You could defer evaluation of the opposite by passing it in a closure and calling the closure when you want the opposite:

```
public enum Direction {
    North({South}), South({North}), East({West}), West({East}), Up({Down}), Down({Up})
    private def opp
    Direction(opp) {
        this.opp = opp
    }
    public opposite() {
        return opp()
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Direction.each { d ->
        println "${d} ... ${d.opposite()}"
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
North ... South
South ... North
East ... West
West ... East
Up ... Down
Down ... Up
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like half of the `Directions` are not initialized when the enum constructor is called. That is, when you call `North(South)`, South hasn't been initialized. It's next in line.

You're caught in a chicken/egg paradox where *all* of the enum constants must be initialized before *one* of them can be. It seems like you will need to reorganize some of your code to account for this. I might suggest:

```
public enum Direction {
    North(1), South(~1), East(2), West(~2), Up(4), Down(~4);

    private int value;

    Direction(int d){
        value = d;
    }

    private int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Direction opposite(){
        for (Direction d : Direction.values()) {
            if (value == ~(d.getValue())) 
                return d;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This utilizes the bitwise operator `~` to distinguish opposites.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. A direct copy/paste of this code gives me a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` when I try to iterate over `Directions`, though. I'm not too keen on what this means. Any ideas?

Comment: @Benjamin It means pretty much exactly what it says. Can you put a try/catch block around the offending line and catch the Error, then call `getException()` on the error? That should give you a little more information about what exactly went wrong.

Comment: @Benjamin I fixed the problem, it was a mistake on my part. I don't know if this answer is still helpful, but the code has been corrected.